# Does creating an instance of a child class automatically create its super class object?

Tags: java, inheritance

If I create an object of sub class then will the super class object also be created from which the sub class is inherited? If not then how by creating a sub class of Thread class (in multi-threading) calls the Thread class constructor and creates a Thread object?

Answer (score 16):

An instance of the subclass *is* an instance of the superclass. Only one object is created, but as part of that creation, constructor calls are chained together all the way up to `java.lang.Object`. So for example:

```
public class Superclass {

    // Note: I wouldn't normally use public variables.
    // It's just for the sake of the example.
    public int superclassField = 10;

    public Superclass() {
        System.out.println("Superclass constructor");
    }
}

public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    public int subclassField = 20;

    public Subclass() {
        super(); // Implicit if you leave it out. Chains to superclass constructor
        System.out.println("Subclass constructor");
    }
}

...

Subclass x = new Subclass();
System.out.println(x instanceof Subclass);
System.out.println(x instanceof Superclass);
System.out.println(x.superclassField);
System.out.println(x.subclassField);
```

The output of this is:

```
Superclass constructor
Subclass constructor
true
true
10
20
```

... because:

- The first thing any constructor does is call either another constructor in the same class, or a superclass constructor. So we see "Superclass constructor" before "Subclass constructor" in the output.
- The object we've created is (obviously) an instance of `Subclass`
- The object we've created is *also* an instance of `Superclass`
- The single object we've created has *both* fields (`superclassField` and `subclassField`). This would be true even if the fields were private (which they usually would be) - the code in `Subclass` wouldn't be able to *access* a private field declared in `Superclass`, but the field would still be there - and still accessible to the code within `Superclass`.

The fact that we've got a single object with *all* the state (both superclass and subclass) and *all* the behaviour (any methods declared within `Superclass` can still be used on an instance of `Subclass`, although some may be *overridden* with more specializd behaviour) is crucial to understanding Java's approach to polymorphism.

Comment: It is worth noting that the sub class object has all the fields that any superclass declares. That is key to it being able to function as an object of any of its superclasses.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: Thanks, will add that into the example.

Comment: Interesting catch: what if both (super and sub) classes define same variable? as only one instance is allocated within memory, and object reference refers to that particular chunk of memory (where the subclass object, with all the super classes' members is allocated), how then Java distinguishes `this.fieldName` of the superclass. from `fieldName` of child class? if you invoke, from your subclass, superclass's method which prints `this.fieldName`, & you also define `fieldName` in the sub class.. then `this` should be referring to the same instance.. yet, it will print superclass's member..

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: Yes, because fields aren't polymorphic. In the superclass, `this.fieldName` can *only* mean the field defined in the superclass.

Comment: @JonSkeet so, then even if they're part of the same (hypothetical) instance, they still have a bit of difference on the memory level.. no? because, as far as I understand, `this` is just physical address of the memory `1x0100x01` whatever.. and JVM needs to somehow distinguish between data defined with same identifiers within same memory location. If my claim is correct, then `this` reference from the superclass method and `this` reference from the child class method should be referring to different memory parts.. but at the same time, object is created in one memory address..

Comment: I agree with the point that superclass instances are not instantiated.. and rather child class is instantiated but in a bit *specific* way (containing all the [even private] members of all the ancestors). One thing which still makes me scratch my head a bit, is that I think, there should be some logical scoping or delimitation of the memory areas.. otherwise, again - `this` clashes in my understanding for child and superclass members, when they define members of the same type and identifier. I hope my point is clear.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri: The JVM doesn't need to use the names. I'm afraid its really not clear to me what your mental model of the objects is, but the fields are separate fields, there's no concept of one field overriding another, and the code in the superclass can only refer to the fields that it's aware of. This will be my last comment here - if you need more information, I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Youre only creating one object when you create a subclass of another. It is an instance of both the subclass and all its parents. Example, I create a cat object. It is a cat, and at the same time a feline, mammal, and animal, and an Object.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an object, it gets one piece of memory with one set of variables to hold the all of its data.

The subclass will contain fields from the child and any fields from its ancestors. So it's a single object that acts like the child and its ancestors.  There is no parent class object created when you create a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

No there Is only one Object there. There Is a misconception that constructor is for creating an object. But It actually for initializing an object. So when we created child class object along with the child class constructor the parent class constructor also executed because of the first line of the child class constructor either `this()` or `super()`. Now, look at the following code.

```
Public class P{    
    public P(){    
        System.out.println(this.hashCode()); // Parent class Constructor    
    }   
}

public class C extends P{    
    public C(){
        System.out.println(this.hashCode()); // Child Class constructor    
    }
}

public class Test{    
    public static void main(String [] args){    
        C c = new C();
        System.out.println(c.hashCode());    
    }    
}
```

If you run the code you can see There is only one HashCode. and an object just has one hashCode. If the parent class object would be created then there must be another hashCode for that object.[image: You can see The hashCodes are same]

Answer (score 0):

Here I am abbreviating with an example that

If a child class object is created, does it automatically create super class object?

```
class P{
  P(){
   System.out.println(this.hashCode()); // it will print 2430287
  }
}

class C extends P{
   C(){
     System.out.println(this.hashCode());   // it will also print 2430287
    }
}

public class Test{

   public static void main(String... args){
        C obj = new C();
        System.out.println(c.hashCode());   //Again, it will print 2430287
   }     
}
```

If you compile and run this code you will find same Object `hashCode` is getting printed. So, this means there is only one object is created.

Now, how is the parent class object being initialized?

In this example only one object is created which is an instance of the child class, but there are two constructors (parent and child) being executed. But the constructor are just in context of child class only.

Answer (score -1):

Nope.
It will not create instance of parent class. But certainly it will create an instance.And the object reference passed to child class. Hence instance is created at parent class and invoked by child class constructor. and child class methods operates.